# Observable with another included array with an array-filter

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, observable

I have got an observable with Notes

```
this.notes$ = this.NoteService.notes$

notes$ = 

0: {id: 4, user_id: 1, body: null, reminder: null, created_at: '2022-08-22T17:44:37.000000Z', …}
1: {id: 3, user_id: 1, body: 'die neuere', reminder: null, created_at: '2022-05-22T10:04:26.000000Z', …}
2: {id: 2, user_id: 1, body: 'Klappt das mit den Notizen?\n\n\nAuch mit Absätzen?', reminder: '2022-05-22 00:00:00', created_at: '2022-05-15T19:34:36.000000Z', …}
3:
body: "Meine Lieblingsnotiz"
created_at: "2022-05-15T18:13:43.000000Z"
id: 1
reminder: null
tags: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, name: 'Arbeit', slug: 'arbeit', created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
1: {id: 4, name: 'Backlog', slug: 'backlog', created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
title: "Test Notiz"
updated_at: "2022-05-15T18:13:57.000000Z"
user_id: 1
```

Now, I have switches in the html page, where I like to activate a filter for the tags.
I push the filter to an additional array,

```
['backlog', 'arbeit', 'email']
```

but I find no way to the filter the observable by the array filter. I was thinking about something like

```
this.notes$ = this.NoteService.notes$.pipe(
      map(notes=> notes
        //.filter(t=> (!t.tags || t.tags.some(ai => this.filterTag.includes(ai))))   
        //.filter(t=> t.tags?.length > 0 && t.tags?.includes(this.filterTag) 
        //.filter(t=> t.tags!=undefined && t.tags.includes(this.filterTag))
        ))
```

Maybe you have an idea for me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in a different way

```
this.notes$ = this.NoteService.notes$.pipe(
      map((notes => notes
        .filter(t=> this.filterTaginNote(t)
        
      ))))
  ;
```

```
filterTaginNote(note: Note){
    if (this.filterTag.length == 0){return true}
    if (note.tags){
      for(var i = 0; i < note.tags?.length; i++){
        if (this.filterTag.includes(note.tags[i].slug)){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if its an array, then perform the ususal logic, else just find that string inside the array using the `includes` method of array. If no tags exist, then we  return the original array itself!

```
this.notes$ = this.NoteService.notes$.pipe(
  map(notes=> notes.filter(t=> 
               t.tags && t.tags.length ? 
                   (
                   Array.isArray(this.filterTag) ? 
                     t.tags.some(x => this.filterTag.includes(x)) : 
                        t.tags.includes(this.filterTag) 
                          ): true
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when I activate eg the switch input for email, it filters everything except the notes without tags.

Comment: @Philipp ok no problem, just fine tune this query to suit your requirement!